# recording microphone audio using NAudio in a console application

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio

my code runs and creates a test.wav but this file dosent contain aything. i am trying to run this code in a console application. please help

```
        using System;
        using System.Media;
        using NAudio;
        using NAudio.Wave;

        class sound
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0);
                Console.WriteLine("Now recording...");
                WaveInEvent waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
                waveSource.DeviceNumber = 0;
                waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, deviceInfo.Channels);

                //waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);

                string tempFile = (@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1.wav");
                WaveFileWriter waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveSource.WaveFormat);
                waveSource.StartRecording();

            }

            //void waveInStream_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
            //{
            //    wavefile.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            //}

        }
```

and can someone please explain what do the lines which are commented mean. i am a beginner in programming.

when i compile the program it gives 2 errors:
Error 1: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'sound.waveSource_DataAvailable(object, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs)'    C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\sound\sound\Program.cs  18  49  sound

Error   2   The name 'wavefile' does not exist in the current context   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\sound\sound\Program.cs  28  21  sound

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Media;
using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;

class sound
    {
        static WaveFileWriter waveFile;
        public static void Main()
        {
            //WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0);
            Console.WriteLine("Now recording...");
            WaveInEvent waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
            //waveSource.DeviceNumber = 0;
            waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

            waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);

            string tempFile = (@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1.wav");
            waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveSource.WaveFormat);
            waveSource.StartRecording();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop");
            Console.ReadLine();
            waveSource.StopRecording();
            waveFile.Dispose();
        }

        static void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            waveFile.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the `StartRecording` methods start some capture loops that periodically raises the `DataAvailable` event to allow the user collecting the recorded data. In your example code the event handle properly append the recorded data to the file `tempFile`. Both the function `waveInStream_DataAvailable` and the `waveFile`   must be declared as static.

Comment: tempFile is just a string that store the file name. for saving sound waveFile is used .... but how do i append recorded data to it.

Comment: by uncomemnting the commented lines, and declaring wavefile as a static member of the class, and the function too.

Comment: I did what u said the program runs fine. but it still dosen't record anything

Comment: check the data, are VytesRecorded different from zero? How to you stop the recording? If you don't close the file you arre writing on there is chanches you loose the content