# WaveIn' type not found in NAudio.Core for console application

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm building a console app using NAudio.Core to capture my mic. I've installed the package, but the 'WaveIn' type is missing, preventing me from using it. I'm using Visual Studio 2022, version 17.8.3, and my framework is 6.0.

I've tried reinstalling, cleaning, checking references, and target framework compatibility.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// Using NAudio.Core for console apps, but WaveIn not found
// using NAudio.Core;

namespace PersonalAssistant
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Attempt to create a WaveIn instance (this line would cause the error)
                // WaveIn waveIn = new WaveIn();  // Error: The type or namespace name 'WaveIn' could not be found

                // Code to configure and start audio recording would go here

                Console.ReadLine();  // Keep the console app running
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39367972/17034

Comment: you need the full NAudio package, not just NAudio.Core which contains the cross-platform parts of NAudio, but not the Windows-specfic bits like WaveIn

Comment: Mark, would you document the Readme.md on NAudio Git Hub to include details about each package? It took many searches to find this comment I'm responding to, which partially explains what NAudio is .Core is. It would be nice to know what works cross-platform and what doesn't by package. Also, is .Core referring to the core of NAudio or .NETCore? I'm finding onboarding with the new NAudio a bit difficult for a cross-platform app because I'm not sure what I can use. (I came from 4.7.2 old naudio in windows, now moving crossplatform with .Net8)